# Checking Boolean variables in a sequence

Tags: python, boolean

So, I have an array, containing tuple instances of `True` and `False` that are determined by a user input. An example could look like this:

```
array = [True, True, False, False, True, True, True]
```

I want to check if these are fulfilling of certain conditions. My current attempt at this is:

```
if (array[0], array[1], array[4], array[5], array[6]) is False and (array[2], array[3]) is True:
```

Obviously, that is completely incorrect and not doing what I want it to do, but I honestly can't find the correct method anywhere.

Comment: `if all(test[2:4]) and not any(test[:2]+test[4:]):`? I wouldn't expect a syntax error from what you've written - it makes no logical sense, but appears to be valid Python.

Comment: That expression is **not** a *SyntaxError*, though it may have other errors. The code you post has a NameError because 'array' is not 'Test'. Also, there are IndexErrors because you access 7 elements but have only 5 in the list. Finally, a tuple is never a boolean so your expression will always evaluate to false.

Comment: @jonrsharpe

if all(test[2:4]) and not any(test[:2]+test[4:]):
TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: what is test here @Jay provide `Test` variable content provide full trace back

Comment: @Jay then apparently `test` is a single boolean, not a sequence.

Comment: _test_ is _array._ I forgot to change the name when pasting from my source. Sorry!

Comment: @Jay asper your sample you will get list index out of range error there is something other then what you are sharing could you more precise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**`all`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) and [**`any`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any). These check whether all or any elements of a sequence are equivalent to `True`:

```
>>> array = [True, True, False, False, True]
>>> not any(array[0:2]) and all(array[2:4]) and not any(array[4:7]) 
False
```

Answer (score 2):

replace `,` with `and` like this:

```
if (Test[0] and Test[1] and Test[4] and Test[5] and Test[6]) is False and (Test[2] and Test[3]) is True:
```

Comment: Don't use `is False`; use `not`.  Similarly, you can drop `is True`.

Comment: @Kevin what about `Explicit is better than implicit.` ?

Comment: Oh, OK.  Then let's write things like `((foo == bar) is True) is True`.  Clearly that's much more explicit.